# Convert Excel BLOB to javascript array

Tags: javascript, excel, blob, google-apps-script, xls

Using Google Apps Script, I seek to extract the cell contents of an Excel file (.xls) (delivered as a Gmail attachment) and deposit those cell contacts into a 2-dimensional javascript array[ ][ ].

```
var excelFile = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0].getMessages()[0].getAttachments()[0];
```

At this point, I have a BLOB with ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel".

How do I convert this “Excel” blob into a 2D (Google Apps Script / javascript) array I can use?

Illustrative note: I want to do what’s described [here](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/wiki/index.php?title=Reading,_parsing,_and_extracting_data_from_Excel_files#Read_from_BLOB) only using Google Apps Script / javascript.

UPDATE:
Methods for accomplishing this the way I have described seem sparse. Approaching it differently, perhaps I could (programatically) convert the Excel file to a Google Drive Spreadsheet? Then the data extraction is trivial using Google Apps Script.
Perhaps someone from Google support could explain how to programatically convert an Excel file in a Gmail attachment to a Google Drive spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can do it using Apps Script now, but there is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019) requesting for this feature. You can star the issue to vote for it and be notified of updates.